# "Beside" VS "Next to" VS "By"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions, word-meaning, difference

As you know, the prepositions "beside" and "next to" are more or less synonymous. However, there are some nuances between them. Long story short, "beside" is more formal than "next to" Also, **"beside"** means there is no space between the two things. So they stick together. While, **"next to"** means there is nothing else between the two objects. However, they could be separated by some space.
On the other hand **"by"** means "near", but a lit closer than "near".
Irrespective of the fact that "beside" is more formal and "next to" is a bit more casual, I was wondering whether I have been wrong in defining the following pairs as correct or incorrect:

1.a. Come and sit beside me. (**Correct**) 
1.b. Come and sit next to me.(**Incorrect** --- doesn't sound idiomatic to me) 
1.c. Come and sit by me.(**Incorrect** --- the same as 'b')

2.a. I live beside the sea.(**Correct**) 
2.b. I live next to the sea.(**Incorrect**) 
2.b. I live by the sea.(**Correct --- the most natural to me. However it depends on the space between the sea and the house.**)

3.a. I parked my car beside the post office.(**Incorrect**) 
3.b. I parked my car next to the post office.(**Correct**) 
3.c. I parked my car by the post office.(**Correct**)

4.a. There is a shop beside my house.(**Correct**) 
4.b. There is a shop next to my house.(**Correct**) 
4.c. There is a shop by my house.(**Correct**)

Please help me to be able to distinguish between these two prepositions.

PS. I have considered the [similar thread](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/159144/are-next-to-beside-and-near-synonyms-or-there-is-a-difference-between-the). Unfortunately, I didn't find it that helpful, though.

Comment: There's an idiom 'sitting next to Nellie' which refers to learning a task by watching how an experienced worker does it. To me, 'sitting beside' someone implies a wish for intimate conversation, but you find yourself 'sitting next to' someone on the bus or in the theatre just because they happen to have the adjacent seat.

Comment: I don't know where you got all these "correct / incorrect" classifications from, but they're more or less worthless. In any given context, one particular phrasing might be more common than another, but they're all perfectly valid. And ideas like ***"beside" is more formal than "next to"*** are complete nonsense (for most purposes, that's neither true nor useful).

Comment: @FumbleFingers regarding the formality degree please have a look on these links: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-beside-and-vs-next-to/amp/ or  https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/4203200 and regarding those "correct"/"incorrect" please read my question more carefully again! I wrote: "**I was wondering whether I have been wrong in defining the following pairs as correct or incorrect**."

Comment: @A-friend: I'm not sure what you expect me to do with those links. If they caused you to have that mistaken idea about different levels of "formality", they're just plain *wrong*. Note that ***next to, by,*** and ***beside*** (not ***besides***, which is mistakenly used in the first link) all have a range of different meanings, ***some of which overlap***. In some contexts, one term might be more "natural" than another, but the actual choice made will rarely reflect any difference in *meaning*.

Comment: Point taken @FumbleFingers. Thank you very much for your informative comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of these examples are incorrect. I would personally prefer "next to" in casual speech but "beside" sounds perfectly fine as well.

"By" is sometimes more idiomatic, especially for "I live **by** the sea". But it can be less specific as to the distance, similar to "near".